# How do I successfully manipulate numbers taken from user input? (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, input, nan

I'm trying to create a confirm box that will take two numbers from an input type="number"> tag and multiply or add them with the use of a confirm box but the result returned is NaN. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<input id="number1" type="number">
<input id="number2" type="number">
<input type="submit" value="Start Process" onclick="decisionDemo()">
```

JavaScript

```
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");

function decisionDemo(){
    if(confirm("Would you like to multiply or add?")){
        alert("You multiplied for the result of "+ number1*number2);
    }
    else{
        alert("You added for the result of "+ (number1+number2));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, `document.getElementById("number1")` will return only *HTML Element*, if you want to get the value inside the textbox you have to use `document.getElementById("number1").value` ...

**Second**, you place the two statements, `var number1 = document. ...` and `var number2 = document. ...` outside the `decisionDemo()` method, so that, it will be executed only once. You should place those statements inside the `decisionDemo()` method.

**Third**, `document.getElementById("number1").value` will return `string` value. So, if you want to perform arithmetic calculation, you need to parse them to a sort of number, such as Integer or Float.

```
function decisionDemo(){
    var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    number1 = parseFloat(number1);
    number2 = parseFloat(number2);
    if(confirm("Would you like to multiply or add?")){
        alert("You multiplied for the result of "+ number1*number2);
    }
    else{
        alert("You added for the result of "+ (number1+number2));
    }
}
```

You might face [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) in result when user enter invalid numbers.

You can use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether your input is valid or not

Comment: Amazing, Thanks for the in depth reply. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the numbers using `parseFloat`

```
var number1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value),
    number2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number2").value);
```

`.value` means the value of the input element.

Then you need to move these two definitions inside of your `decisionDemo` function. And change, "Would you like to multiply or add?" to "Would you like to multiply?".

In your case, your `number` variables were holding DOM elements, not their values. And thus you were multiplying/adding DOM elements.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/R7YhP/1/)

Full Code Redone:

```
<script>

function decisionDemo(){
    var number1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value),
    number2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number2").value);

    if(confirm("Would you like to multiply?")){
        alert("You multiplied for the result of "+ (number1*number2));
    }
    else{
        alert("You added for the result of "+ (number1+number2));
    }   
}
</script>

<input id="number1" type="number">
<input id="number2" type="number">
<input type="submit" value="Start Process" onclick="decisionDemo()">
```

Comment: Ummm, [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) doesn't take a radix argument.  That's `parseInt()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oops! I completely forgot! Edited.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Just fixed a typo for you, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am extremely sorry. I did not at all intend to blame you. Looks like some serial down voting going on here

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know why someone down voted, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

NaN in JavaScript stands for 'Not a Number', which is exactly your case.

the variables are holding 2 DOM objects, instead of 2 numbers, you need to convert them to numbers before you do any arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just get value of them, **number1.value* number2.value**

```
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");

function decisionDemo(){
    if(confirm("Would you like to multiply or add?")){
        alert("You multiplied for the result of "+ (number1.value* number2.value));
    }
    else{
        alert("You added for the result of "+ (number1.value+number2.value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then please try code from post, and then this code, before writing about differences. Author didn't took value from input, they multiple DOM elements, instead they value of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check also whether the element is found or not. [IsNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) and [IsFinite()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) might useful.

```
function decisionDemo() {

                var number1 = 0;
                var number2 = 0;

                if (document.getElementById("number1") != null && isFinite(document.getElementById("number1").value)) {
                    number1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value);
                }

                if (document.getElementById("number2") != null && isFinite(document.getElementById("number2").value)) {
                    number2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number2").value);
                }

                if (confirm("Would you like to multiply or add?")) {
                    alert("You multiplied for the result of " + number1 * number2);
                } else {
                    alert("You added for the result of " + (number1 + number2));
                }
            }
```